# How is knowledge of lambda calculus applicable in Computer Science and Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, lambda-calculus

If I want to do research in computer science and machine learning, is it important to have a well-rounded understanding of lambda calculus?

Comment: These terms have no precise meaning.

Comment: There's no meaning beyond the ordinary English-language meaning of those words.

Comment: OK. Point taken.

Comment: I have edited my question and my question should now be on topic.

Comment: Not really, no. It's still very broad and open-ended and doesn't have a well-defined, subjectively correct answer. Please do have a look at the [help] and our short [tour] for more information on what sorts of things we cover.

Comment: OK. I see your point now.